# Name the index column of a dt::datatable()

Tags: r, dt

Is there a way to give a name to the index column of a datatable?

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  rownames_to_column("myid") %>% 
  datatable(iris, rownames = F)
```